# Adsense: if no ads available fallback url not working

Tags: adsense

I had a fallback, clickable image working when no ads were being delivered by Adsense on my website pages. However, today I have just discovered that in such cases Chrome is now automatically downloading the "other URL" page and Firefox gives the option to open it, rather than the image being delivered in the ad slot. I have used the absolute path to the "other URL" and the full path to the image:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="https://blahblah" target="_top"><img src="https://www.blahblah/image.png" alt="" /></a>    
</body>
</html>
```

The only major change I have made recently was to convert the site from http to https, but I have changed the appropriate links accordingly, to no effect. Has anyone encountered a similar problem and, if so, what was the fix? Many thanks.

Comment: how do you test the fallback url?